# How to do data masking for xmldatatype(oracle database) in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I have oracle table with xml type column with xml data,that xml data has some elements which needs to be masked such as phonenumber, data of birth, firstname and lastname etc.. using informatica. Currently I have been following below approach.
Tried exporting xml data into xml files and masked using xml transformation using informatica and updated those xml columns using update quires manually. Is there any way to read the xml data directly from oracle xml type column and apply mapplet and load it into target table or any other generic approach to achieve this solution ?

Comment: have you tried using xml transformation?

Comment: I have already tried XML transformation but we can read using XML parser transformation but not write into XMLtype column directly right. I am looking for direct table to table XML data masking approach

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do exactly as you describe. Read data from Oracle, pass the xml data through a Mapplet that will use `XML parser`, do the masking and will use `XML Generator` to put data back alltogeher into single column.

Mapping:

```
Source--xml_column-->Mapplet----\
      \----->all_other_columns---->Joiner-->Target
```

Mapplet:

```
Input_coulmn-->XML parser-->Exp_Masking-->XML Generator-->Output
```

What have you tried and what errors did you encounter?

Comment: I already have mapplets created for the columns. I tried creating Mapping -> Source - XML Parser - Mapplet - XML generator - Target. but i am not able to link the output of xmlgenerator to target table.

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Why can't you connect the ports? What is the problem? Is there any message on the bottom bar of the application?

Comment: Yes, i am getting error - "concatenation disallowed on transformation from source to target" on the bottom bar of the application.

Comment: Tried using a joiner? You're connecting a pipeline with an active transformation - Powercenter won't allow that. Even if there's just one row. BTW: it would help if you'd post some screens and error messages.